# optimization for select of select in mysql query

Tags: mysql, select, query-optimization

My mysql query is taking nearly 7 seconds to fetch data, where I used select of select.

```
SELECT s.id
     , s.user_id
     , COUNT(s.od_status) od_status
     , (SELECT count(t2.od_status) 
          FROM subscription t2 
         WHERE od_status <> 3 
           AND t2.od_status <> 7 
           AND t2.od_status <> 8 
           AND t2.user_id = s.user_id 
           AND DATE(IF(t2.rescheduling_delivery_date IS NULL, t2.dated, t2.rescheduling_delivery_date)) BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT('2021-07-26', '%Y-%m-01') AND '2021-07-26'
        ) od_status_count 
  FROM subscription 
  LEFT 
  JOIN users u
    ON u.id = s.user_id 
 WHERE DATE(IF(s.rescheduling_delivery_date IS NULL, s.dated, s.rescheduling_delivery_date)) BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT('2021-07-26' , '%Y-%m-01') AND '2021-07-26' 
 GROUP 
    BY s.user_id;
```

I need to optimize the above query, the thing I am getting 7 secs is by adding below `select of select` in above query

```
(select count(t2.od_status) from subscription t2 where od_status<>3 and t2.od_status<>7 and t2.od_status<>8 
and t2.user_id=subscription.user_id and 
date(IF(t2.rescheduling_delivery_date IS NULL,t2.dated,t2.rescheduling_delivery_date)) 
between DATE_FORMAT('2021-07-26' ,'%Y-%m-01') AND '2021-07-26') as od_status_count
```

any suggestion to optimize or another way to use that.

NOTE: I have given `index` to the `user_id` in `subscription` table

Comment: If you need performance, the first thing I would do is to rephrase the query to remove the `IF()` function. Second, I would remove `date()` function as well.

Comment: @TheImpaler Thanks will check that and any suggestions for select of select

Comment: Hi @DroidDev: convert corelated subquery part with INNER JOIN and replace IF() with COALESCE() or CASE for gain better performance.

Comment: You are LEFT JOINing a table from which you appear to select no columns. What am I missing?

Comment: @radocaw  no issues in fetching data but the thing is it takes 7 secs to fetch.

Comment: ? But the LEFT JOIN doesn't do anything !?!

Comment: Is `users` : `subscriptions` a 1:many relationship?  If so, `SELECT subscription.id ... GROUP BY user_id` is meaningless.

Comment: Please provide `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`

Comment: @RickJames Thanks and I already solved. And am posting the answer now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [@RahulBiswas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16364625/rahul-biswas) suggested, I changed the subquery to LEFT JOIN and the query executed in `0.16` secs

```
select 
`subscription`.`id`, 
`subscription`.`user_id`, 
COUNT(subscription.od_status) as od_status ,
x.od_status_count
from `subscription` left join `users` on `users`.`id` = `subscription`.`user_id`
left join(
  select t2.user_id,count(t2.od_status)as od_status_count from subscription t2 where od_status<>3 and t2.od_status<>7 and t2.od_status<>8 
and 
date(IF(t2.rescheduling_delivery_date IS NULL,t2.dated,t2.rescheduling_delivery_date)) 
between DATE_FORMAT('2021-07-26' ,'%Y-%m-01') AND '2021-07-26'
group by t2.user_id)x
on x.user_id=subscription.user_id    
where date(IF(subscription.rescheduling_delivery_date IS NULL,subscription.dated,subscription.rescheduling_delivery_date)) 
between DATE_FORMAT('2021-07-26' ,'%Y-%m-01') AND '2021-07-26' 
group by `subscription`.`user_id`
```

I changed the subquery to joins as below,

```
left join(
select t2.user_id,count(t2.od_status)as od_status_count from subscription t2 where od_status<>3 and t2.od_status<>7 and t2.od_status<>8 
and 
date(IF(t2.rescheduling_delivery_date IS NULL,t2.dated,t2.rescheduling_delivery_date)) 
between DATE_FORMAT('2021-07-26' ,'%Y-%m-01') AND '2021-07-26'
group by t2.user_id)x
on x.user_id=subscription.user_id
```

Comment: Hi @DroidDev Thanks for this query and really honored for mentioning my name.

Answer (score 0):

For the optimizer to be able to use indexes you'll need to:

- Rephrase your query. Remove the IF() function by using `OR` or `UNION`/`UNION ALL`.
- Remove date() function and replace it by timestamp comparison instead.

If you don't do that you can still get a somewhat better performance by adding an index for the subquery. This is the simplest option, but won't really get great improvements. You can add the following index:

```
create index ix1 on subscription (user_id, od_status);
```

For further improvement in performance you can use a covering index instead:

```
create index ix1 on subscription (
   user_id,
   od_status,
   rescheduling_delivery_date, 
   dated, 
   rescheduling_delivery_date
);
```